# NSArray and NSMutable Array. Type of property and type of ivar are not the same

Tags: objective-c, class

I'm working through the big nerd ranch guide for Objective-C programming.

There is an example and challenge in chapter 21 that I've been stumped on. (I actually finished the challenge but I used previous code from an example) I'd like to actually understand what I did.

It has to do with declaring a property of type NSArray and then declaring the setter method to be of type `NSMutableArray`. Can anyone tell me what is going on here? What happens "behind the scenes" with this statement.

```
@property (nonatomic copy) NSArray *assets
```

and what is happening in these two files? Please explain at the lowest-level possible. Thanks!

BNREmployee.h

```
@interface BNREmployee: BNRPerson
{
    NSMutableArray *_assets
}
@property (nonatomic copy) NSArray *assets 

@end
```

BNREmployee.m

```
@implementation BNREmployee 

- (void)setAssets:(NSArray *)a
{
    _assets = [a mutableCopy]; //What did this actually do? 
}

- (NSArray *)assets
{
    return [_assets copy];
}
```

Comment: The "external face" (ie, property view) of `assets` is an immutable array, but internally a mutable version is maintained.

Comment: (Keep in mind that there is no rule that says that a property must have any specific variable backing it up.  It could derive its value from a DB query or a web request.)

Answer (score 0):

An `NSMutableArray` IS an `NSArray` (it is a subclass), so it just gets assigned normally. Nothing special happens behind the scenes.

An example I can give looking at your models would be assigning a `BNREmployee` object to a `BNRPerson` pointer which will work fine.

```
BNREmployee *employee = [BNREmployee new]; // or whatever initializer

BNRPerson *person = employee; // works fine, an employee IS a person
```

You can always assign an `NSMutableArray` to an `NSArray` pointer, but not the other way around.

**Edit**

> "The property has type NSArray, which tells other classes, If you ask
>   for my assets, you are going to get something that is not mutable.
>   However, behind the scenes, the assets array is actually an instance
>   of NSMutableArray so that you can add and remove items in BNREmployee"

By exposing the public property as an immutable type you are letting any potential callers know that they can't modify the property without explicitly calling the mutator on the object. <s>It also lets callers know once they get the collection, its contents will never be changed out from under them. This is the standard contract when exposing an immutable property.</s> *As pointed out in one of the comments below, there can be cases where a return type is immutable but the underlying object is actually mutable internally and can change, so good practice would be to make a copy when receiving the object if you are not already receiving an actual immutable copy, such as in the case of `[NSView subviews]`.*

Making the actual underlying variable a mutable type acts as a convenience to allow the owning class to modify it internally easily. Functionally, you could accomplish the same thing by making it a regular `NSArray` and constantly recreating it whenever you want to change its contents (such as `array = [array arrayByAddingObject:object]`). This will of course be slower than just modifying a mutable instance.

Comment: The assignment is to an instance variable of type `NSMutableArray`, not `NSArray`, so calling `copy` in the setter method would be the wrong thing to do.

Comment: I missed that part, modifying answer.

Comment: I think the point of the example is that the array's mutability is a private implementation detail, while its public interface provides immutable access. Exposing the mutable array through the accessor methods would conceptually violate encapsulation.

Comment: Jiehr that's correct.In the book it states "The property has type NSArray, which tells other classes, If you ask for my assets, you are going to get something that is not mutable." However, behind the scenes, the assets array is actually an instance of NSMutableArray so that you can add and remove items in BNREmployee" I'm just having a hard time understanding that statement...

Comment: In that case that is perfectly fair. I will remove the last sentence in my answer, but the rest of it should answer your question.

Comment: @user3912305 I will modify my answer to address that statement.

Comment: "It also lets callers know once they get the collection, its contents will never be changed out from under them. This is the standard contract when exposing an immutable property." This is not correct. As a caller, one must not assume that an array received from another object from a property of immutable type won't actually mutate. *You* can't mutate it, but there's no standard design contract that it won't mutate out from under you. For a counterexample, see `-[NSView subviews]`.

Comment: @KenThomases in the example he provides, that is what is happening, standard or not (because the accessor is making the copy). I suppose it depends on the internal implementation of the API whether a copy is required or not but in my opinion it is more consistent design to say that if the return type is immutable, the actual value is final and won't change. You're right though as I hadn't considered that case.